# Overlap replace regex?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string

> work 1 work 2 work 3 work 4 work 5

I want to obtain

> work 1 work 21 work 321 work 4321 work 54321

I use this command but not work

```
    (?<=work\s(\d)+.)(work)(\s\d+)
    $2$3$1
```

The problem is that it does not record the information replaced after the first occurrence and could do to save the changes after each occurrence.

When I apply the command I get

> work 1 work 21 work 32 work 43 work 54

Comment: What's your programming language?

Comment: regex c#  , i use sharpdeveloper

Comment: This is not possible with one regex pass if the number of "work+digits" groups is variable.

Comment: the problem is that it does not record the information replaced after the first occurrence and could do to save the changes after each occurrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Regex.Replace` while *aggregating* matches :

```
  String source = "work 1 work 2 work 3 work 4 work 5";
  String aggregate = "";

  // work 1 work 21 work 321 work 4321 work 54321
  String result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\d+", // or  @"(?<=work\s)\d+" pattern
    match => aggregate = match.Value + aggregate);
```

Comment: @zero625: all the answers (`sln`'s and `Wiktor Stribiżew`'s ones) exploit the same idea: regular expression + aggregation; the implementations, however, are slightly different (the answers uses *groups*, when I've performed look behind in `@"(?<=work\s)\d+"` pattern; I prefer lambda to delegates etc.). So the similar examples are the other answers

Comment: An unanchored lookbehind is somewhat costly in terms of regex performance, that is why I always prefer to stay away from them if I can use a capturing group. Also, the `\d+` regex matching one or zero digits will match any digit sequences, not only after "work ". @zero625: BTW, if an answer proved helpful, please always consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need an overlapping regex matching, you need to be able to match each `work`+space+digits and save the digits value to update at each iteration.

The regex is reduced to a mere [`work (?<num>\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=work+(%3f%3cnum%3e%5cd%2b)&i=work+1+work+2+work+3+work+4+work+5) (matches `work`, a space and captures one or more digits into the "num" group).

Use a callback method inside a `Regex.Replace` method:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
public class Test
{
    public static string num = string.Empty;
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "work 1 work 2 work 3 work 4 work 5";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"work (?<num>\d+)", Repl));
    }

    public static string Repl(Match m)
    {
        num = m.Groups["num"].Value + num;
        return string.Format("work {0}", num);
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/m8Jsep)

Comment: Dmitry and sln suggest identical solutions using an aggregate and an anonymous method. The idea is the same: use the [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate to update the num variable.